# Sales order collection error

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-grid

I want to add custom product attribute to sales order grid, and here is my code below,

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass())
$vendor1_total = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttribute('vendor1_total');
 $collection->getSelect()
            ->join(array('ce1' => 'catalog_product_entity_varchar'), 'ce1.entity_id=main_table.product_id', array('vendor1_total' => 'value'))
            ->where('ce1.attribute_id=' . $vendor1_total->getAttributeId())

            ->columns(new Zend_Db_Expr("CONCAT(`ce1`.`value`"));
```

and Im getting Unknown column error, and query is,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` AS `soas` ON soas.parent_id=main_table.entity_id and soas.address_type = "shipping"
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` AS `sales/order_item` ON `sales/order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `ce1` ON ce1.entity_id=sales_flat_order_item.product_id
 LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `order` ON order.entity_id=main_table.entity_id
```

Of course the error is correct, there is no column name of `product_id` in `sales_flat_order_grid` . But I tried to replace the table name - `main_table` with `sales_flat_order_item` where the column is exist. But still its taking old table `main_table` - `sales_flat_order_grid`. So I want to changes this `main_table` to `sales_flat_order_item` (If it will not affect other parts) or how to use this table `sales_flat_order_item` to fetch my column into grid. Please help me.